# What does a + before a string means in javascript

Tags: javascript

There is a line of code in angular2.

```
this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

What is the "+" means before "this.route.snapshot.params['id']"?

I also see "+" added before a folder name such as "+detail" in angular2-webpack-starter.

Do they have the same meaning?

Comment: `+` is used for a quick changing type of number-ish `strings` into `number`, e.g. `+"5"` will return `5`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using + in Javascript is a quick way to cast a string to a number as long as the string is already in the form of an integer or float.

```
+'5000' // yields 5000
+'2.5'  // yields 2.5
```

If the string contains any character that is not an integer (or decimal in the case of a float), this method will return NaN.

```
+'5n'  // yields NaN
+'abcd'  // yields NaN
```

Comment: Not necessarily integers. You could have something like `+"2.5"`.

Comment: Thanks for catching my mistake!  I update the answer to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxyw4.png)

In short if you put + operator in front of string which contains Number
then always get number other than that you will get NaN.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).